# bash: if / elif / fi gets not evaluated properly

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've got a script which checks for a specific PNG file in three directories. The first one is local and gets checked first. The second one is a remote share and gets checked only if the file is not available on the local hard drive. 
Under some circumstances the third directory (an archive directory) gets searched recursive for the file.

For some reasons, the second part of my if / elif / fi construct doesn't work. I can't see at all why the PNG file is not found, even it is definitely available. I double checked for typos and every variable, I added log-statements everywhere. The last try was splitting up the evaluation of "is a file" and "is greater 0 bytes" to get more logmessages. when I'm looking for the file manually (with "find" or a filemanager), I can find it at once, but the script doesn't find it.

The first and third part are working fine however, and now I'm a bit at a dead end, I have no idea why my script doesn't find the file. 
Can someone help me out here?

This is my code:

```
#!bin/bash
[...snip...]
find $printjobtemp -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname $printjobsearch | \
while read filename
do
    # check if file is > 0 Bytes
    # skip if 0 bytes, process if larger than 0 bytes
    if [ -s "$filename" ]
    then

        if [ -f "$pngdir/$pngname" ] && [ -s "$pngdir/$pngname" ]
        then
            # png is available & > 0 bytes -> move printjob to printjobdirectory
            writelog "    found $pngname in $pngdir"

            # create a copy for the archive
            fileoperation=`cp -fv $filename $printjobdir/archive/$printjobfile 2>&1`
            writelog "    cp $fileoperation"

            # move printjob to printjobdir
            fileoperation=`mv -fv $filename $printjobdir/$printjobfile 2>&1`
            writelog "    mv $fileoperation"

        # if not in pngdir: check in pngtemp
        elif [ -f "$pngtemp/$pngname" ]
        then
            writelog "    found in $pngtemp/$pngname - checking size..."
            if [ -s "$pngtemp/$pngname" ]
            then
            writelog "    found $pngname in $pngtemp and size is >0"

            # move png to pngdir
            fileoperation=`mv -fv $pngtemp/$pngname $pngdir/$pngname  2>&1`
            writelog "    mv $fileoperation"

            # create a copy for the archive
            fileoperation=`cp -fv $filename $printjobdir/archive/$printjobfile  2>&1`
            writelog "    cp $fileoperation"

            # move printjob to printjobdir
            fileoperation=`mv -fv $filename $printjobdir/$printjobfile  2>&1`
            writelog "    mv $fileoperation"
        fi
        # png not in pngdir & pngtemp
        # check if it is an old printjob (reprint) and search in pngarchive
        elif [ $pngage -gt $pngthreshold ]
        then
            writelog "    png not found and printjob is considered as \"old\" - checking $pngarchive"
            pngarchivefile=`find $pngarchive -type f -iname $pngname -printf '%p\n' | sort | tail -n 1`
            writelog "    searchresult: $pngarchivefile"

            # check if searchresult contains a value
            if [ -n "$pngarchivefile" ]
            then
                # searchresult is not NULL -> move the png back to $pngdir
                writelog "    moving $pngarchivefile to $pngdir"

                # move png to pngdir
                fileoperation=`mv -fv $pngarchivefile $pngdir/$pngname  2>&1`
                writelog "    mv $fileoperation"

                # create a copy for the archive
                fileoperation=`cp -fv $filename $printjobdir/archive/$printjobfile  2>&1`
                writelog "    cp $fileoperation"

                # move printjob to printjobdir
                fileoperation=`mv -fv $filename $printjobdir/$printjobfile  2>&1`
                writelog "    mv $fileoperation"

            else
                # searchresult is NULL - complain about this and do nothing
                writelog "    $pngname not found in archive - this should be checked manually!"
            fi
        else
            writelog "    $pngname not existing or 0 Bytes - skipping $printjobfile"
            # writelog "    pngtemp: $pngtemp/$pngname"
        fi
    fi
done
[...snap...]
```

kind regards,

dura

Comment: What exactly is the 'second part', the first `elif`? 
Also note that you have one `fi` too much at the end.

Comment: yes, the elif ist the non-working part, it doesn't get evaluated or doesn't find the file (can't tell from the output. The first check and the "search in archive-directory" check are working.
Please note that the "fi" results from an incorrect copy&paste from the originating script. The code-block shown above is part of a larger script and executed only if there is a printjob waiting. The "fi" is part of the check for printjobs.

Comment: try `set -x` or look into other shell debugging techniques

Comment: try quoting your variables in the `mv` command sub. and, honestly - why `mv` in a command sub anyway? and also - with `find` do you also do `-type f`?

Comment: Thank you, I will add correct quoting - the script isn't finnished and I will do this before i "release" it.

regarding mv: I want & need to get the output for "mv" and "cp" in the logfile.

I will see whats happening with "set -x"

Comment: I can't see why the second elif is not within if/fi - please disregard on fi instance at the end of my snippet. 
I do -type f on the most invocations of "find" and will do this on all (where possible) before the script is finnished.
I'm analyizing with set -x later this day when I'm at the office.

Comment: Ah yes, I was fooled by your mis-indented `fi`.

Comment: We really can't help unless you give us a minimal example that reproduces the error. Something we can copy and try and then debug. For all I know, you have no output from your `find` command. I also see that you're checking whether `filename` is empty but then never use `filename` again. You need to give us everything we need in order to help. An example directory structure with the file name that isn't found, so we can actually reproduce your error.

Comment: All your file operations are using filename without qoutes: `cp -fv $filename`. Are files with spaces (or other odd characters) in the filename?.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you change your ``` `...` ``` structures to $(...), are easier to read and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten your `if...fi` blocks confused. Here's the current structure of your script:

```
if [ -f "$pngdir/$pngname" ] && [ -s "$pngdir/$pngname" ]
then

elif [ -f "$pngtemp/$pngname" ]
then
    if [ -s "$pngtemp/$pngname" ]
    then

    fi
elif [ $pngage -gt $pngthreshold ]
then
    if [ -n "$pngarchivefile" ]
    then

    else

    fi
else

fi
fi
```

As you can see, you have an extra `fi` there. If you're not getting a syntax error, then the final `fi` is ending something from the previous part of your script which is, therefore, probably not doing what you think it is.

On a separate note, `[ -f $pngname ]` checks whether the target is a regular file. If you just want to check if it exists and are sure that, if it does, it will certainly be a file and not a directory or whatever, you can skip the `-f` and just use `-s` directly. `[ -s file ]` will return false if the file doesn't exist.

I can't tell you exactly why your script is failing since you're not showing the rest of the script. If you edit your question and give a minimal working example that reproduces the error, I can update this answer. Another possibility is that your target file is actually a link, in which case, the `[ -f file ]` will fail. If you also need it to work for links, replace the `[ -f file ]` tests with `[ -e file ]`.

Comment: Hi
I edited my question. I can't disclose the full script but my snippet now contains the full loop so one can see that the last "fi" belongs to the check if the printjobfile is empty) I can not rely on the file being a regular file and I want to be really sure that the found file is really what it appears to be. Thats the reason I'm testing it for being a regular file and having a size > 0 bytes. 0-byte files happen to exist when the file is being created and I dont want to fetch empty/unfinnished files. I do not need to check for links though.

Comment: @dura-zell OK, I'll have a look. A few quick observations: i) you don't need the `\ ` after the `|`; the pipe itself acts as a line break (this is not an error, just inelegant). ii) your script will fail if any of the results of the `find` command contain whitespace. iii) you don't need to `[ -f file]` the results of `find`, you've already told `find` to only return regular files. iv) you don't need to check the file's size really. If you have GNU `find`, use `find .... -not -empty` and, if not, use `-size +0`. Fixing those issues should help you simplify the script and find the problem.